# Cropping Image changes rotation in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiimage

I am using one simple cropping on `UIImage`, however after cropping when we check the final image, it gets rotated in iPhone. Below is my code used for cropping.

```
CGRect visibleRect;
float scale = 1.0f/scrollView.zoomScale;
visibleRect.origin.x = scrollView.contentOffset.x * scale;
visibleRect.origin.y = scrollView.contentOffset.y * scale;
visibleRect.size.width = scrollView.bounds.size.width * scale;
visibleRect.size.height = scrollView.bounds.size.height * scale;
finalImage = imageFromView(displayImageView.image, &visibleRect);

UIImage* imageFromView(UIImage* srcImage, CGRect* rect) {
    CGImageRef cr = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(srcImage.CGImage, *rect);
    UIImage* cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cr];

    CGImageRelease(cr);
    return cropped;
}
```

Please let me know if i am doing any kind of wrong thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call this method after crpping it

```
-(UIImage*)rotateImage:(UIImage*)image
```

{

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0 , 0, image.size.width , image.size.height), [image CGImage]);


CGContextRotateCTM (context, radians(90));

CGImageRef cgImage = nil;

cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];


return img;

}
```

Comment: Hi Sachin so after retrieving finalimage from cropping function, i need to call rotate function above after that.

Comment: what if one image is landscape mode and the second one is portrait. How to know when to rotate and when to not rotate?